# Mysql Merging Databases - Same Schema

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

So about a year ago i have taken over the development and management of the database for the organisation i work for. (in-house developer).

The organisation is a national organisation, but started out in one state. The dev company in charge of development at the time, decided to take the shortcut method of opening the database to other state by duplicating the schema and putting it under a different name.

So, what i am left to work with is 4 duplicate database, with years of information already in them which we can't lose.

It largely acts like a training database. Site has Classes, People Participant in classes, so there are links which cant be messed up.

```
Site:
(AI)site_id

Classes:
(AI)class_id
site_id

Person:
(AI)person_id

Participants:
(AI)id
person_id
site_id
```

of course, this is just one small part of the database.

I am wanting to turn this into a partial Tennant based database, where i can separate the information that needs separating (classes, sites ect), and where national information (like person where a person could be in any state) is global.

```
Site:
(AI)site_id
state_id

Classes:
(AI)class_id
site_id
state_id

Person:
person_id

Participants:
(AI)Id
person_id
class_id
state_id
```

I am hoping someone has been in a similar situation and might be able to offer some advice or guidance, or perhaps even suggest a tool to help facilitate this change.

Comment: how about if you get someone off of http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/ to jumpstart and jam it into one database and tune the indexes ?

Comment: certainly something i can take into consideration.